# Is XQuery 3.1 designed for advanced JSON editing?

Tags: json, xquery

XQuery 3.1 introduced several [JSON functions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#maps-and-arrays). I was wondering if these functions were designed with advanced JSON editing in mind.

As far as I can tell, these functions only work for simple JSONs, like for instance...

```
let $json:={"a":1,"b":2} return map:put($json,"c",3)
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}
```

and

```
let $json:={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3} return map:remove($json,"c")
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
```

The moment the JSON gets a bit more complex:

```
let $json:={"a":{"x":1,"y":2},"b":2} return map:put($json?a,"z",3)
{
  "x": 1,
  "y": 2,
  "z": 3
}

let $json:={"a":{"x":1,"y":2,"z":3},"b":2} return map:remove($json?a,"z")
{
  "x": 1,
  "y": 2
}
```

Obviously `map:put()` and `map:remove()` do exactly what you tell them to do; select the "a"-object and add or remove an attribute.
However, when I want to edit a JSON document, I'd like to edit the entire document. And as far as I know that's not possible with the current implementation. Or is it? At least something like `map:put($json,$json?a?z,3)` or `map:remove($json,$json?a?z)` doesn't work.

For the removal of the "z"-attribute I did come up with a custom recursive function (which only works in this particular use-case)...

```
declare function local:remove($map,$key){
  if ($map instance of object()) then
    map:merge(
      map:keys($map)[.!=$key] ! map:entry(.,local:remove($map(.),$key))
    )
  else
    $map
};
let $json:={"a":{"x":1,"y":2,"z":3},"b":2} return
local:remove($json,"z")
```

...with the expected output...

```
{
  "a": {
    "x": 1,
    "y": 2
  },
  "b": 2
}
```

...but I wasn't able to create a custom "add"-function.

I imagine advanced JSON editing can be done with some pretty advanced custom functions, but instead I would very much like to see that something like `map:put($json,$json?a?z,3)` would work, or otherwise an extra option which lets `map:put()` put out the entire JSON document, like `map:put($json?a?z,3, <extra-option> )`.

Or... I'd have to settle with the notion that XQuery isn't the right choice of course.

Comment: What is `let $json:={"a":1,"b":2} ` supposed to be? XQuery 3.1? I don't think so. Some pseudo syntax?

Comment: If your attempt makes any sense, then the expression `?a?z` simply selects the empty sequence in your input JSON `{"a":{"x":1,"y":2},"b":2}`. I don't think you can expect the lookup operator to suddenly define a new map structure, only because you use it in a parameter to `map:put`. But anyway, there is some ongoing work on XPath and XQuery 4 at https://qt4cg.org/ and in a W3C community group, perhaps you can participate there to form some more powerful manipulation operations on maps (and arrays?).

Comment: @MartinHonnen Well, that must be `xidel`. It defaults to `--json-mode=default`. With `--json-mode=standard` I'd have to enter `let $json:=map{"a":1,"b":2}` as *you* would probably expect.

Comment: @MartinHonnen So I guess it's save to say XQuery 3.1 isn't the right choice at the moment?

Comment: Not being able to spell out the right syntax and semantics of a language but to make judgements about it seems not really something I would want to start any debate with. Your syntax has a defined semantic but to expect it to somehow serve other means won't work in any programming language, I think. There are always options in a language like writing functions, in the case of XQuery to convert JSON to XML, even there your choice of update options often depend on the vendor/implementor. I don't know what edit operations you consider fundamental and whether other JSON query languages offer any.

Comment: I agree that updates on map/array structures without additional helper functions are tedious with XQuery 3.1. If updates are required, we tend to convert JSON data to XML.

Comment: @MartinHonnen `let $json:={"a":1,"b":2}`  is the [JSONiq object constructor](https://www.jsoniq.org/docs/JSONiqExtensionToXQuery/html-single/index.html#idm48114976) syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that doing what I call deep update of a map is quite difficult with XQuery 3.1 (and indeed XSLT 3.0) as currently defined. And it's not easy to define language constructs with clean semantics. I attempted to design a construct as an XSLT extension instruction - see https://saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!extensions/instructions/deep-update -- but I don't think its anywhere near a perfect solution.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you, Michael. Maybe @BeniBela would be interested in assisting you with creating such a "deep update"-function for XQuery 4, or possibly a custom `xidel` function for the time being?

Comment: Updates primitives had been defined for JSONiq (https://www.jsoniq.org/docs/JSONiqExtensionToXQuery/html-single/index.html#section-json-updates), but I believe they haven’t made it into the reference implementation. They could also be considered for XQuery 4.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, maps in JSONiq have object identity, which is not true of XQuery maps (which are pure functional data structures). That makes the semantics of deep update much easier to define, but makes it more difficult to make simple operations such as put() and remove() efficient.

Comment: That extension looks very interesting. The example is a little butchered. I do not know where to put that information so I leave it here
`action = "map:put(., 'quantity', ?quantity * 2"/> ` should be `action = "map:put(., 'quantity', ?quantity * 2)"/>`

Answer (score 2):

I wanted the same thing, so wrote my own surrogate XSLT functions, `tan:map-put()` and `tan:map-remove()`, which do deep map replacement and removal:
https://github.com/Arithmeticus/XML-Pantry/tree/master/maps-and-arrays

These can be incorporated in an XSLT workflow via `xsl:include` or `xsl:import`, or in an XQuery one via `fn:transform()`. Some of the other functions may be useful, too. If these functions don't do exactly what you want, they might catalyze your own variation.

Answer (score 1):

In XQuery 3.1, you are supposed to write a recursive function for such things. You could put all you functions in a module file, and then load the module when you need them...

Besides that, Xidel has an object editing extension from before JSONiq and XPath 3.1. For a global mutable variable (without let), you can write:

```
$json:={"a":{"x":1,"y":2,"z":3},"b":2},
(($json).a).z := 4   


$json:={"a":{"x":1,"y":2,"z":3},"b":2},
$json("a")("z") := 4
```

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't just type `($json).a.z:=4`?

Comment: First I tried to use `$json.a.z:=4` and `$json?a?z:=4`, but that did not work (former needs `--dot-notation` flag, and latter is not implemented), so I added more parentheses

Answer (score 0):

[#comment119588453_67652693](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67652693/is-xquery-3-1-designed-for-advanced-json-editing#comment119588453_67652693) by @ChristianGrün:

> *If updates are required, we tend to convert JSON data to XML.*

I'm a [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) user and last week (with a little help from @BeniBela) I've had a look at whether this could be done with `json-to-xml()`, Xidel's own [`x-replace-nodes()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-replace-nodes) and `xml-to-json()`. The answer is yes. Thanks for the hint.

For reference and for anyone interested, here's 1 example.

To change key "c" in `{"x":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},"y":2}` to "d":

```
$ xidel -s '{"x":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},"y":2}' -e '
  xml-to-json(
    x:replace-nodes(
      json-to-xml(
        serialize($json,{"method":"json"})
      )//fn:map[@key="x"]/fn:number[@key="c"]/@key,
      attribute key {"d"}
    )
  )
'
{"x":{"a":1,"b":2,"d":3},"y":2}
```

[Xidel online tester](https://videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%7B%22x%22%3A%7B%22a%22%3A1%2C%22b%22%3A2%2C%22c%22%3A3%7D%2C%22y%22%3A2%7D&=&extract=declare%20default%20element%20namespace%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%3B%0Alet%20%24xml%3A%3Djson-to-xml(serialize(%24json%2C%7B%22method%22%3A%22json%22%7D))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%24xml_updated%3A%3Dx%3Areplace-nodes(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24xml%2F%2Fmap%5B%40key%3D%22x%22%5D%2Fnumber%5B%40key%3D%22c%22%5D%2F%40key%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20function(%24x)%7Battribute%20key%20%7B%22d%22%7D%7D%0A%20%20%20%20)%0Areturn%20(%0A%20%20%22Input%3A%22%2C%22%22%2C%0A%20%20serialize(%24json%2C%7B%22method%22%3A%22json%22%7D)%2C%22%22%2C%0A%20%20%22Converted%20to%20XML%3A%22%2C%22%22%2C%0A%20%20serialize(%24xml%2C%7B%22indent%22%3Atrue()%7D)%2C%22%22%2C%0A%20%20%22Key%20name%20updated%3A%22%2C%22%22%2C%0A%20%20serialize(%24xml_updated%2C%7B%22indent%22%3Atrue()%7D)%2C%22%22%2C%0A%20%20%22Converted%20back%20to%20JSON%3A%22%2C%22%22%2C%0A%20%20xml-to-json(%24xml_updated)%0A)&=&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto).

Comment: If you receive the error `err:XPST0003: This language feature is not available in the selected language. XQuery is required to use constructors` when attempting to copy-paste this example, make sure you're using Xidel 0.9.9, which is required for XQuery 3.1 syntax support.